# Ubuntu 18.04 on DELL XPS 15, Intel profile for display, NVIDIA for CUDA computation

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, dell, cuda, xps

I'm using DELL XPS 15 9570 with Ubuntu 18.04. The laptop has a NVIDIA GTX 1050Ti that I need to use for some computational tasks. One problem is that, when using nvidia profile for display via `prime-select`, the laptop suffers from random hard freeze frequently, which I couldn't find a way to deal with. So now I'm trying to find a Intel profile for display, and only use the GPU for CUDA stuff.

I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057853/nvidia-card-for-cuda-and-intel-integrated-card-for-display-on-ubuntu-16-04-dell) quite interesting, and tried that but no luck. The output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

`prime-select` confirms the nvidia profile is enabled.

Comment: did you fixed it?

Comment: @lrkwz unfortunately not. And still I couldn't find anything that works for this specific problem online.

Answer (score 1):

One hacky way which works for me is starting ubuntu with the NVIDIA GTX 1050Ti enabled. Then run `sudo prime-select intel` and logout. Then log in again and run `sudo prime-select nvidia`. Now gnome is running on the intel device but your GPU is available for CUDA stuff. You can verify this by running `nvidia-smi`.