# Dell XPS 15 9570 GTX for CUDA and Intel GPU for GUI

Tags: nvidia, xorg, cuda

I have been trying to get the integrated Intel GPU to be used for GUI and the Nvidia GPU to do CUDA work only in my XPS 15 9570.
So far I have tried with the solutions from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057853/nvidia-card-for-cuda-and-intel-integrated-card-for-display-on-ubuntu-16-04-dell) which apparently does nothing at all, i.e. no problems but nvidia-smi still reports Xorg processes. And also tried [this other solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061551/how-to-configure-igpu-for-xserver-and-nvidia-gpu-for-cuda-work) that makes the laptop to stay in a login loop.

The only way I have achieved what I want is via prime-select

1. prime-select intel
2. Logout my session
3. prime-select nvidia

but as you can imagine is quite annoying to do this every time I shutdown my computer. Anyone here has any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The login loop problem is usually related to having the user home set up wrong for the display.  Google for Ubuntu login loop for the solutions.